# How to make left and right sided collapsible tree using d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know how to have a collapsible tree using d3js. I also need to know how to make a [mbostock collapsible tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) expand in both left and right directions with json data in format:

```
var treeData = [
{
"name": "Top Level",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "Level 2: A",
    "parent": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 2: B",
    "parent": "Top Level"
  }
  ]
},
{
   "name": "Top Level",
   "parent": "null",
   "children": [
    {
       "name": "Level 2: A2",
       "parent": "Top Level",
       "children": [
       {
           "name": "Son of A2",
           "parent": "Level 2: A2"
       },
       {
           "name": "Daughter of A2",
           "parent": "Level 2: A2"
       }
     ]
   },
   {
       "name": "Level 2: B2",
       "parent": "Top Level"
   }
 ]
}
];
```

where treeData[0] expands to right side and treeData[1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) to left side with single root node (i.e., '*Top Level*' )

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by left and right ? want the tree vertical ?

Comment: Hi Dragon Slayer thanks for your response, I actually want to represent ,nodes that root depends on to left side and nodes dependent on root to right side. but in mbostock example i can represent only any one of my requirement as i can display nodes only on one side of the root.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/2073ba4c2d640236e2e2

Comment: This looks good but , is there any other way that can full fill my requirement by making little modification to mbostock example?

Comment: in http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html , it is given how to make vertical tree,but I am unable to combine horizontal and vertical trees,please help me in this ,so that i can change it further to left and right tree.

Comment: Please start your sentences with capital case and end with a ".". Without it looks your text so bad. Anyways good question.